# Hibernate: app doesn't close after crash

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My app just creates an EntityManager and after that I throw a RuntimeException on purpose. If I place the RuntimeException line before I create the entity manager, the exception is correctly caught by main and the app closes (as expected). But if any exception occurs after that, the exception is caught (I can see the stacktrace) but the app keeps running and I have to kill it. In Netbeans, the thread's state is "zombie".

**libs used**

- Hibernate 4.3.1 Final: all jars from **jpa** folder and **required** folder ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.3.1.Final/))
- Database connector: jtds 1.3.1 ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/))

My test class

```java
package test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // throw an exception here, app closes as expected

        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();


        // throw an exception here, it runs forever
        throw new RuntimeException();    
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433/database"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any *EntityManagerFactory* could get hold of critical resources which need proper cleanup; in your example it's probably a thread managing the connection.
You must make sure the factory is closed: normally frameworks take care of proper shutdown, but if you manage the resources yourself you have to enclose the next blocks in a *finally* block.

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
try {
    // rest of your application here
}
finally {
    factory.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to close your application on purpose? I'm not sure I follow what you're attempting to do here.

If all you want to do is stop the application, you can call,

```
System.exit(0)
```

which signifies that the execution of the program was successful, or pass in other numbers to signify a failure.

Comment: No. The point is if I place the RuntimeException line before I create my entities, the exception is correctly caught by main and the app closes (as expected). But if any exception occurs after that, the exception is caught (I can see the stacktrace) but the app keeps running.

Comment: Try debugging your program in an IDE so you can see what is going on, and verify which thread is throwing the exception. Also, post the stack trace above.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans. There is just one thread (main), and after the exception its state is "zombie" haha